# how to make this a generic method in java?

Tags: java, generics

```
public void setSRC(int var)
{
    if (src== null)
    {
        src = new int[1];
        src[0] = var;
    }
    else
    {
        int i = 0;
        int[] temp = null;
        temp = new int[src.length];
        temp = src;
        i = temp.length;
        src = new int[i+1];
        for (int j =0; j < temp.length ; j++)
                    src[j] = temp[j];
        src[i] = var;

    }
}
```

I am looking to make this method generic or template method. Any sort of help is appreciated. Looking forward to it

Comment: I'm assuming src is of type int[]?
So this function will take an int as input, and if src hasn't beet set yet, will create an int[] of size 1 containing the input.  If src has already been set, it tacks on the input to the end of the src array.  Since you're using primatives, you have to manually grow the array and copy the data.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be making an array that grows each time an element is added? That could get very costly over time. I'd suggest using a generic ArrayList instead. It'll grow on its own and likely achieve what you're looking to do.

Comment: please clean up your code or write what your function should do? Looks like a mass.

Comment: I actually wants to have a dynamic array in Java. how can i get it if i don't use the above code? I am new to java..

Comment: @Kam: Like statenjason said, you should use an ArrayList, which precisely implements a dynamic array in Java. If you really wanted to implement it yourself, you would double the size of the array allocated when it gets full and you need to add more. (You also need to keep track of the current size in a separate variable.) The way you are doing it is very inefficient -- every time you add something it has to copy the entire array, making adding an element O(n). However, if you double the size (or increase it by any fixed percentage) when it gets full, then adding becomes amortized O(1).

Answer (score 5):

Use Collections, instead of arrays. Apart from the fact that Java arrays don't mix with generics, they are actually designed to be appended to. Your code can be replaced by:

```
private List<T> src = new ArrayList<T>();

public <T> void setSRC(T var) {
    src.add(var);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can define src as a generic collection like that.

Comment: Well, I did assume that Kam was free to change the declaration of the src field, even though he did not say so in his question.

Comment: it asks me to create class T if I use the above code for generic? is it right?

Comment: You have to substitute another class for T. (For example, Integer.) Or, you have to make the entire containing class generic. See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf for a good tutorial.

Comment: this code won't compile. the `T` in the type of `src` is different from the `T` inside the method, because you declared it as a new type variable specific to the method

Answer (score 0):

Use Generic collections in place you use Java arrays.

```
public <T> void setSRC(T var)
```

instead of

```
new int[1]
```

use

```
Collection<T> collection = new ArrayList<T>();
```

Comment: Generics doesn't add anything here. It's the same as `public void setSRC(Object var)` and `Collection<Object> collection = new ArrayList<Object>();`

Answer (score 0):

This  notation is quite confusing for Java beginners. So here's the jqno's example for Integer type values:

```
private List<Integer> src = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void setSRC(Integer var) {
    src.add(var);
}
```

Now src is an ArrayList that can only store Integer type objects, and that's very close to your question. It can't store int values (int type is not an object) but Java 5/6 will convert int to Integer if necessary (autoboxing) so you can call setSRC with (int) i.

If you want to use arrays and need to change the size, then have a look at the System.arraycopy(..) method.

Answer (score -1):

This code will create a class with a generic data type and will store a dynamic array of objects of that data type.

```
import java.util.*;
class Test2<T>
{
    private Collection<T> src = new Vector<T>();

    public void setSRC(T var)
    {
        src.add( var );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Test2 t = new Test2<Integer>();
        t.setSRC( 5 );
        Test2 t2 = new Test2<Double>();
        t.setSRC( 5.5 );
    }
}
```

The thing is, if this is all you're doing, there's no need to bother.  It looks like you're trying to write your own dynamic array class, and Java has plenty of classes in the [Collections Framework](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/collections/) to choose from.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Now, if you're trying to do something specific, tell us what you're trying to accomplish and we can provide a better answer.